# Create TSQL view from function with DECLARE variables not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can easily create a SQL view from a function using the code below.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE object_id = object_id('InvoicedItemsView') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'IsView')=1)
DROP VIEW [dbo].[InvoicedItemsView]
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[InvoicedItemsView]
AS
    SELECT * FROM sp_GetInvoicedItems('201803', '201803', '201803', '201803',NULL,NULL) AS InvoicedItems 
GO

/* SELECT all data from the created view */
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[InvoicedItemsView]
GO
```

HOWEVER, why can I not create a View with DECLARED variables for the function??
The below code causes TSQL to have several error messages thrown.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE object_id = object_id('InvoicedItemsView') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,'IsView')=1)
DROP VIEW [dbo].[InvoicedItemsView]
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[InvoicedItemsView]
AS
    DECLARE @P0 AS CHAR (6) = '201803', @P1 AS NVARCHAR (6) = '201803', @P2 AS CHAR (6) = '201803', @P3 AS NVARCHAR (6) = '201803', @P4 AS INT = NULL, @P5 AS NVARCHAR (4000) = NULL;
    SELECT * FROM sp_GetInvoicedItems(@P0, @P1, @P2, @P3, NULL,NULL) AS InvoicedItems 
GO

/* SELECT all data from the created view */
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[InvoicedItemsView]
GO
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand First, Yes, the function is a table-valued function. (see full function below)
What I am attempting to do is build a view based on those values being passed into that function.   Those values can change based on a selection criteria.  If there is a better way, i.e. one that works, I would love to learn how to do that.  Thank you!
```
   Customer_BAccountID int NOT NULL,
   Customer_AcctCD nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
   Customer_AcctName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
   Customer_NoteID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please don't add the body of a function to a comment. It's unreadable even if it's short enough and you get the formatting right, and it's rare that both of those are true. Add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare variables in a view; `CREATE VIEW` is just a wrapper for a `SELECT` (or a `SELECT` that starts with a CTE), and can't be parameterized. Trying to hard-code these variables with values inside the view seems to defeat the purpose of using variables in the first place: in order to change the values, you need to alter the view.

Next, you *seem* to be trying to say:

```
SELECT * FROM <stored_procedure>;
```

You can't interact with a stored procedure this way. If this is in fact a table-valued function with a bad name, you should rename it, because on top of the fact that giving a function a prefix of `sp_` is misleading, you shouldn't be using the `sp_` prefix on *anything*. ([Background](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix#:%7E:text=TL%3BDR%20version%3A%20YES.,is%20still%20a%20no%2Dno.).)

You can get close to what you're looking for like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.InvoicedItemsView 
AS 
  SELECT i.* -- bad practice, see sqlblog.org/selstar
  FROM 
  (
    VALUES -- this "kind of" looks like a variable list:
    (
      CONVERT(char(6),        '201803'), 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(6),    N'201803'),
      CONVERT(char(6),        '201803'), 
      CONVERT(nvarchar(6),    N'201803'),
      CONVERT(int,            NULL),
      CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), NULL)
    )
  ) AS d(P0, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5)
  CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.sp_GetInvoicedItems(P0, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5) AS i;
```

Comment: FYI, basically what I am trying to do is create a View from a function that returns a table created 'on the fly' from variables passed to it.

Comment: @NetAdmin SQL Server doesn't support parameterized views, so I think you're going to need to change your goal.

Comment: I took your advice and rethought about it.  The parameters I am trying to pass are basically Financial Monthly Periods.  So, here is what I did that works.  Instead of passing those Financial periods to the function, I picked an historical date in time in the past and using DATETIME(year, -1, GETDATE()) on a specific column from the dataset, I can build that view without it pulling massive amounts of rows over which negatively impacts performance.  Thank you for all your help